# Schema design for a (suspected) many-to-many relation

Tags: database, database-design

I am creating an application for tracking the configurations of machines on a network. "Configuration" broadly defines the products/service/OS/applications installed on the system. A change in any one of them brings about a change in the configuration. 
The information is obtained using scanners. The data is already parsed. I need to figure out a way to efficiently store the data.

The basic idea is

1. Each IP will have a configuration identifier along with timestamp information and flags that identify the data as current or historical
2. Each configuration in turns consists of entries of multiple types. So for each configuration identifier, we have at most three types of entries (1-OS,2-Service, 3- Applications)
3. Each type of entry can have multiple entries. For example Type 1 (i.e. - OS) can have multiple entries of the type a) Microsoft Windows XP b) Microsoft Windows 7 etc.

I am stuck at defining a set of suitable tables that helps me in fulfilling following objectives

1. Get to know the OS/Service.Application information for each IP
2. Recognize changes/no changes/reverting in configuration of an IP

The data I get is the IP and the set of entries and their type identifier. E.g.

```
IP - x.y.z.w : 
Entries - Microsoft Windows XP :1(Type-OS), 
          Apache HTTP 2.3 :2(Type-Service),
          Mozilla Firefox :3(Type - Application)
```

Earlier when I was not bothered about the configuration and just had to store the entries I had the following scheme

```
Table ip_map : id int, ip char #Table that keeps track of IPs
Table ip_ref: id int , ip_id references ip_map(id), t_stamp timestamp, archived bool, type smallint  #Table that keeps IPs and type
Table current_network: id int, ip_ref_id references ip_ref(id), port int, vendor, product,version  #Table that stores actual entries
```

i.e. - I identified entries using IP and type information.

If I need to implement configuration, the scheme should be somewhat like

```
ip_map:
+--+-------+
|id|ip     |
+--+-------+
|1 |x.y.z.w|
+--+-------+

ip_config:
+--+------+----------+--------+----------+
|id|ip_id |t_stamp   |archived|config_num|
+--+------+----------+--------+----------+
|1 |1     |1212231313|    1   |    1     |
|2 |1     |1212299999|    0   |    2     |
+--+------+----------+--------+----------+
```

I am stuck in the step after this. Ideally config_num is a foreign key that points to primary key of config table. But as configuration is made up of different types, it is does not seem possible. This is what I have in my mind.

```
config:
+--+---+----+
|id|num|type|
+--+---+----+
|1 | 1 | 1  |
|2 | 1 | 2  |
|3 | 2 | 1  |
|4 | 2 | 2  |
+--+---+----+

entry:
+--+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|id|config_id|port|vendor       | product     | version     |
+--+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|1 | 1       | 0  | Microsoft   | Windows     | XP          |
|2 | 1       | 0  | Microsoft   | Windows     | 7 Home      |
|3 | 2       | 80 | Apache      | HTTP Server | 2.3.19      |
|4 | 3       | 0  | Linux       | Linux       | 2.6         |
|5 | 3       | 0  | Linux       | Linux       | 2.4         |
|6 | 4       | 22 | OpenSSH     | SSHD        | 4.3p1       |
+--+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

But it breaks consistency (due to missing foreign key between ip_config and config table). IPs may be deleted but there configurations will continue to linger. 
How can the design be altered to accomodate my requirements?

Note: The type information (for each IP or configuration) should ideally be maintained separately because that is how a separate part of program expects it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not say that I understand everything here, so this example may give you some ideas.

Start with `ConfigurationType`, this can be `1- OS; 2- Service ...`

The `Configuration` table holds all possible (permitted) configurations. The `ConfigurationTypeNo` is an integer (1,2,3 ...) for each `ConfigurationTypeID` -- so there is OS (1,2,3 ..); service (1,2,3 ...) etc.

`SystemConfiguration` captures history of configuration-setups for each system. With `TimeChanged` being a part of the PK, it is possible to have same configuration repeated.

`IP_Allocation` tracks history of IP assignments.

[image]

Comment: That is a good option. But I was trying to avoid composite primary keys (Django doesn' support them fully). SO I thought this - ip_config can have a config_id and then we create a new table config with just id field. Another table config_type_map describes the many-to-many relation between config_id and type_id and its own id is used as a foreign key by the table describing the entries

Comment: One way to avoid composite keys (because ORM is giving you trouble) is to use auto-increment-integers for PKs and then simply add unique constraints to DB tables -- for example, you could add `SystemConfigurationID` as a PK to `SystemConfigurationTable` and then add unique constraint on `(SystemID, ConfigurationTypeID, ConfigurationTypeNo, TimeChanged)`. This creates an extra index, but allows for benefits of the selected ORM.